# Remove active class on hover CSS

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

How can I remove the active class when i hover on a navigation. Here is my code

```
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[1])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[1].'">',$navdesc[1] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[2])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[2].'">',$navdesc[2] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[3])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[3].'">',$navdesc[3] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[4])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[4].'">',$navdesc[4] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[5])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[5].'">',$navdesc[5] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[6])) echo 'class="active"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[6].'">',$navdesc[6] ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can do so with jQuery, but I suggest you just use :hover in css (.active:hover) and override the styling u want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this from jQuery:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You can use something like this:

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css's `:Hover` Property which is easiest way , and also
You can add or remove class with the following jquery,

```
$('#elm').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('active') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('active') }
)
```

where `#elem` is the id of your element just give any id to your `<li>`,

and then you can add or remove any class.

**update**

```
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[1])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[1].'">',$navdesc[1] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[2])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[2].'">',$navdesc[2] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[3])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[3].'">',$navdesc[3] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[4])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[4].'">',$navdesc[4] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[5])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[5].'">',$navdesc[5] ?></a></li>
<li  <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $navserver[6])) echo 'class="active lihover"';?>><?php echo '<a href="'.$navlink[6].'">',$navdesc[6] ?></a></li>
```

Then use ,

```
<script>
$('.lihover').hover(          
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('active') }
)
</script>
```

Comment: i want to remove the active class when i hover the mouse to any li

Comment: why is it not working? do i have to do something on the css part?

Comment: i am using jquery ui, pleasae take a look at my code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4urlv76eslpz1j/header.php Thnks.